# Как переопределить поле унаследованного класса другого типа

Tags: java, ооп, override

Как переопределить поле унаследованного класса Second другого типа

```
public class First{
  private int id; 
 
 
  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
 
 
  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id= id;
  }
}
```

```
public class Second extend First{
  private String id;
 
  @Override
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }
 
 
  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id= id;
  }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А как вы в родительском классе Стринг id записываете в переменную типа int?

Comment: @had0uken, ошибка в написании примера.

Comment: мне в дочернем классе надо изменить тип поля, в данном примере надо изменить id с int на string. В дочернем класса выдает ошибку в этом методе 'public String getId()', требует public int

Answer (score 1):

Переопределить метод в дочернем классе, отличающийся только типом возвращаемого значения, можно если типы результатов в методах `First::getId` `Second::getId` являются *совместимыми*.  Общим для типов `String` и `int` является `Object`, так что, расширив тип до `Object`в родительском классе можно заставить код скомпилироваться:

```java
class First{
  private int id; 
 
  public Object getId() {
    return id;
  }
 
  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id= id;
  }
}

class Second extends First{
  private String id;
 
  @Override
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }
 
 
  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id= id;
  }
}
```

Однако в такой реализации может быть побочный эффект, так как в дочернем классе возникает *перегрузка* сеттеров: два метода `setId`, но только 1 геттер.

```java
First f = new First();
f.setId(1);
System.out.println(f.getId()); // -> 1

First f2 = new Second();
f2.setId(12);    // вызывается доступный "родительский" сеттер
//f2.setId("b"); // такой метод не определён в классе First!
System.out.println(f2.getId()); // -> null
```

Во втором случае дочерний геттер будет возвращать `null`, так как у переменной с типом родителя нельзя вызвать напрямую сеттер со строковым аргументом.

```java
((Second) f2).setId("b"); // явное приведение к дочернему типу для вызова сеттера
System.out.println(f2.getId()); // -> b
```

"Потерянное" значение в дочернем классе:

```java
Second s = new Second();
s.setId(2);   // неизвлекаемое значение
s.setId("x");
System.out.println("child: " + s.getId());            // -> child: x
System.out.println("parent: " + ((First) s).getId()); // -> parent: x
```

Поэтому для доступа к целочисленному значению в родительском классе всё равно может потребоваться отдельный геттер:

```java
class FIrst {
// ...
    public final int getIntId() { return this.id; }
}
```